# use a list of values from an array in Picker

Tags: react-native, picker

I would like to know if in the React-native Picker I could use a list in an array?
basically I want to call an API and use all of the products in it. For example, I want to list in my dropdown the whole of

> this.state.displayArray

How can I insert this list into something like this: (i took this example directly from the expo documentation)

```
<Picker
  selectedValue={this.state.language}
  style={{ height: 50, width: 100 }}
  onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => this.setState({ language: itemValue })}>
  <Picker.Item label="Java" value="java" />
  <Picker.Item label="JavaScript" value="js" />
</Picker>
```

console.log(this.state.displayArray) returns

```
displayArray Object {
  "cost": 24,
  "created_at": "2020-07-27T21:49:18Z",
  "custom_fields": Object {
    "_161_": "4206",
    "_162_": "4137",
    "_163_": "779",
    "_164_": "0",
    "_165_": "FLY",
    "_166_": "2020-07-27T18:47:58.000Z",
    "_167_": "2020-07-27T19:47:54.260Z",
    "_168_": "21",
    "_169_": "22",
    "_170_": "24",
    "_171_": "611",
    "_300_": "00:59",
  },
  "description": "",
  "family_id": 0,
  "id": 1,
  "incl_tax": 0,
  "is_visible": 1,
  "name": "",
  "photo": "",
  "quantity": 0,
  "reference": "21",
  "stock_status": "1",
  "tax_rate_id": 0,
  "unit": "",
  "updated_at": "2020-09-10T18:58:28Z",
  "weight": 23,
} reference 21
```

Answer (score 0):

```
           <Picker
            selectedValue={this.state.language}
             style={{ height: 50, width: 100 }}
             onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => this.setState({ language: itemValue })}>{
             this.state. displayArray.map(item=>
             <Picker.Item label={item.label} value={item.value} />)
            } 
           </Picker>
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me. It gives me "TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '...this.state.displayArray.map...')"

Comment: **this.state.displayArray** is undefined check the value

Comment: **this.state ={displayArray:[{label:'A',value:'A'},{label:'B',value:'B'}]}** displayArray format should be like this.

Comment: Alright I'm gonna try to correct this. I edited my post to show you what looks like this.state.displayArray.